Cognito don't creates the user profile in your user pool.Importing users into user pools with a user migration Lambda trigger
I am currently working on AWS tenant migration.
We are using AWS Lambda to migrate data to the target Cognito.
The authentication in the source Cognito is successful, and we are getting the expected response.
According to the documentation, we are returning all the necessary responses, but user profiles are not being created in the target Cognito. Why is this happening? Please Help me!!!!!
// this is lambda response
{
  version: '1',
  triggerSource: 'UserMigration_Authentication',
  region: 'xxx',
  userPoolId: 'xxxx',
  userName: 'xxxx',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
    clientId: 'xxxxx'
  },
  request: { password: 'XXXXX', validationData: {}, userAttributes: null },
  response: {
    userAttributes: {
      username: 'name',
      'custom:role': 'x',
      'custom:userId': 'xxxxxxxx',
      phone_number: '+99999999',
      preferred_username: 'name',
      sub: 'uuid'
    },
    forceAliasCreation: false,
    enableSMSMFA: true,
    finalUserStatus: 'CONFIRMED',
    messageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    desiredDeliveryMediums: 'SMS'
  }
}


// migration Lambda trigger code
import {
  AdminInitiateAuthCommand,
  AuthFlowType,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  AdminGetUserCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import { STSClient, AssumeRoleCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sts"

const region = "ap-northeast-1"

const roleARN = "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/XXXX"
const FROM_USER_POOL_ID = "XXXX"
const FROM_CLIENT_ID = "XXXX"

// Replace this mock with a call to a real authentication service.
const authenticateUser = async (username, password) => {
  console.log(username+" + " + password)
  const stsClient = new STSClient({region:region})
  const stsCommand = new AssumeRoleCommand({
    RoleArn: roleARN,
    RoleSessionName: "sts-role-test"
  })
  console.log("assumeRole Invoke")
  const assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(stsCommand)
  console.log(assumeRoleResponse)
  
  const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: region,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SessionToken
    }
  });
  const command = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand({
    ClientId: FROM_CLIENT_ID,
    UserPoolId: FROM_USER_POOL_ID,
    AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
    AuthParameters: { USERNAME: username, PASSWORD: password },
  });
  const result = await client.send(command);
  console.log(result)
  const getUserInputs = new AdminGetUserCommand({
    Username: username,
    UserPoolId: FROM_USER_POOL_ID,
  });
  const userInfo = await client.send(getUserInputs);
  console.log('userInfo')
  console.log(userInfo)
  return result
};

const getUserInfo = async (username) => {
  console.log('getUserInfo')
  console.log(username)
  const stsClient = new STSClient({region:region})
  const stsCommand = new AssumeRoleCommand({
    RoleArn: roleARN,
    RoleSessionName: "sts-role-test"
  })
  const assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(stsCommand)
  const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: region,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SessionToken
    }
  });
  const getUserInputs = new AdminGetUserCommand({
    Username: username,
    UserPoolId: FROM_USER_POOL_ID,
  });
  const userInfo = await client.send(getUserInputs);
  console.log('userInfo')
  console.log(userInfo)
  return userInfo
};

export const handler = async (event) => {
  if (event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_Authentication") {
    console.log("in if UserMigration_Authentication")
    // Authenticate the user with your existing user directory service
    const user = await authenticateUser(event.userName, event.request.password);
    console.log("user is ")
    console.log(user)
    const userInfo = await getUserInfo(event.userName)
    let sub;
    let adminRole;
    let userId;
    let phone_number;
    let preferred_username;
  for (const userAttribute of userInfo.UserAttributes) {
    switch (userAttribute.Name) {
      case 'sub':
        sub = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'custom:role':
        adminRole = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'custom:userId':
        userId = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'phone_number':
        phone_number = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'preferred_username':
        preferred_username = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      default:
        break;
  }
}
    if (user) {
      event.response.userAttributes = {
        username: event.userName,
        'custom:role': role,
        'custom:userId': userId,
        phone_number: phone_number,
        preferred_username: preferred_username,
        sub: sub
      };
      event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED";
      event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
      event.response.desiredDeliveryMediums = "SMS";
      event.response.forceAliasCreation = false;
      event.response.enableSMSMFA = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(event)
  return event;
};

target Cognito response is below and target cognito don't create user-profile.
{
    "code": "NotAuthorizedException",
    "name": "NotAuthorizedException",
    "message": "Incorrect username or password."
}


Here is our current authentication flow:
①The user logs in with an ID and password (using Auth.signIn from aws-amplify/auth in Vue3).
②Cognito evaluates the authentication result and sends an SMS verification code if successful.
③If the ID and password match, the user is redirected to the screen to enter the SMS verification code.
④The user enters the verification code (using Auth.confirmSignIn from aws-amplify/auth in Vue3).
⑤If the verification code is correct, the user is logged into the content.
Has anyone encountered similar issues or can provide guidance on what might be going wrong?
I have also checked the IAM roles but found no issues. Could you provide guidance on what permissions need to be granted and how to set them up?
